# How to fix file path so untar() can open compression?

Tags: r, for-loop, directory, subdirectory

I am trying to loop into each subdirectory and untar the single .tar file and
put the uncompressed data into the same subdirectory containing the .tar file. Can you help fix this loop, I am not seeing why this isn't not working?

This is the output error:

```
 Error in gzfile(path.expand(tarfile), "rb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In gzfile(path.expand(tarfile), "rb") :
  cannot open compressed file './GSE20292 / GSE20292_RAW.tar', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
```

This is what I have tried:

```
# get into the parent directory
setwd("filepath")
# loop through the sub directories (use [-1] to lop off the current   directory: ".")
for (dir in list.dirs()[-1]) {
# get into the sub directory
    #setwd(dir)
# do the do
temp <- list.files(dir, pattern="*.tar")
untar(paste(dir, "/", temp), exdir = dir)
    # pop back up to the parent directory
setwd("../")
};
```

Comment: Not `paste()` but `paste0()` or `paste(sep = "")`, maybe (I didn't try).

Comment: Hi cuttelfish44: it was your second option. `untar(paste(dir,"/",temp, sep = "", collapse = ""), exdir = dir)`

Comment: If you make a answer, will select it. Thanks